# Question: how to get response headers or cookies from http request with php

Tags: php, backend

I'm struggling to get the cookies that coming from the HttpRequest response,
for example, if I made a request no matter what type it is to an API I want to pull the cookies and the headers, if it's possible

Comment: Yes it's possible to get that info in PHP. Have you got a specific issue? Please show your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: `$_COOKIE` and `getallheaders()`